# Testing Airflow Dag in command line

Tags: airflow

From Airflow manual at https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html#testing, I found that I can run something like following to test a specific task:

```
airflow test dag_id task_id
```

When I did, I only got this message:

```
[2018-07-10 18:29:54,346] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
[2018-07-10 18:29:54,367] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
[2018-07-10 18:29:54,477] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2018-07-10 18:29:54,513] {models.py:189} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /var/lib/airflow/dags
```

It doesn't look like it is really running it. Am I misunderstood? Or is there another way to run a DAG locally?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I copied this example call from the paragraph in the page you have linked to:

```
# command layout: command subcommand dag_id task_id date

# testing print_date
airflow test tutorial print_date 2015-06-01

# testing sleep
airflow test tutorial sleep 2015-06-01
```

So just include the **date** as shown above and the DAG task should run as expected.

Comment: why should we add the *date* value to the command?

Answer (score 5):

#### for airflow version 2.4.0

```
airflow tasks test tutorial sleep 2015-06-01
```